# Mongoose: How to post into array inside Schema

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a Company Schema that will hold some data for that company and an array of posts. When a user submits a post I use passport to decode the token and get some user information. Inside that user information there is an object ID which allows me to find the company that the user belongs to.

So now I have found the company that the user belongs to I need to save the submitted post into the board_posts array inside this company

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BoardPostSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});

const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    company_name: {
        type: String
    },
    board_posts: [BoardPostSchema],
});

module.exports = Company = mongoose.model('companies', CompanySchema);
```

```
router.post('/new-opportunity',  passport.authenticate('jwt', { 
    session: false 
}), (req, res) => {
    let user = req.user;
    let newPost = req.body;
    let companyId = user.company_id;

    const boardPost = {
        name: newPost.name
    };

    Company.find({'_id': companyId})
        .then(company => {
            // push boardPost into this company.board_posts array
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution with findByIdAndUpdate:

```js
router.post("/new-opportunity", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;
  let newPost = req.body;
  let companyId = user.company_id;

  const boardPost = {
    name: newPost.name,
  };

  Company.findByIdAndUpdate(
    companyId,
    {
      $push: {
        board_posts: boardPost,
      },
    },
    {
      new: true,
    }
  )
    .then((company) => {
      console.log("Updated compay if found:", company);
      res.send(company);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500);
    });
});
```

Or if you want only update status, you can use [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne):

```js
router.post("/new-opportunity", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  let user = req.user;
  let newPost = req.body;
  let companyId = user.company_id;

  const boardPost = {
    name: newPost.name,
  };

  Company.updateOne(
    { _id: companyId },
    {
      $push: {
        board_posts: boardPost,
      },
    }
  )
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // result.n; // Number of documents matched
      // result.nModified; // Number of documents modified
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "new: true" do, does that just create a new object? If I set it to false would I be able to use a similar method to update a post inside the board_posts array?

Comment: with `{new: true}` option we get the updated object. It is useful to see the updated object so that we can easily understand whether the push worked.

Comment: So if I don't want to return the any data and instead just return a status then I don't need this part?

Comment: @Reece if you aren't interested in the updated object, better to use `updateOne` method, I added is to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$push` and `update`

```js
router.post('/new-opportunity',  passport.authenticate('jwt', { 
    session: false 
}), (req, res) => {
    let user = req.user;
    let newPost = req.body;
    let companyId = user.company_id;

    const boardPost = {
        name: newPost.name
    };

    Company.update({_id: user.company_id},{
         $push{
             //the things you want to add
         }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this is what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `$push`and `findOneAndUpdate` operator. It would look nicer if you use the `async/await` approach.

```
router.post('/new-opportunity',  passport.authenticate('jwt', { 
   session: false 
}), async (req, res) => {
   let user = req.user;
   let newPost = req.body;
   let companyId = user.company_id;

   const boardPost = {
       name: newPost.name
   };

  let response = await Company.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': companyId}, {
     $push: {
        board_posts: "testword1"
     }
  },{ new: true })  //i set this to true so mongodb will return me the new updated document

  res.send(response);

});
```